# Xposed Hook Constructor in Nested Class

Tags: java, android, constructor, inner-classes, xposed

I am trying to hook the constructor of a nested class using Xposed, but I'm getting a ClassNotFoundException for the nested class (SettingsAdapter). However, there is another method in the nested class that it has no trouble hooking. Is there anything wrong I'm doing with the constructor call?

This is the constructor call:

```
findAndHookConstructor("com.angrydoughnuts.android.alarmclock.ActivityAlarmSettings$SettingsAdapter", lpparam.classLoader, "SettingsAdapter", "android.content.Context", "java.util.List", new XC_MethodHook() {
```

And this is the other working method call:

```
findAndHookMethod("com.angrydoughnuts.android.alarmclock.ActivityAlarmSettings$SettingsAdapter", lpparam.classLoader, "getView", "int", "android.view.View", "android.view.ViewGroup", new XC_MethodHook() {
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is the nested class static? Also: please format code sections in your question.

Comment: No, the nested class declaration is `private final class SettingsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Setting> {`

Comment: @F43nd1r  Sorry to dig this up again, but what would happen if the nested class were static? I'm running into this issue now with a different hook.

Comment: Hooking static nested classes doesn't differ from normal classes (besides the name).

Comment: @F43nd1r How would it differ, if SettingsAdapter were static in this case?

Comment: the constructor wouldn't have the implicit parameter

Comment: Yes, removing the implicit parameter fixed it, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inner classes have an implicit parameter, which holds the super instance. In your case that would be a reference to `ActivityAlarmSettings`.

You can either try

```
findAndHookConstructor("com.angrydoughnuts.android.alarmclock.ActivityAlarmSettings$SettingsAdapter", lpparam.classLoader, "com.angrydoughnuts.android.alarmclock.ActivityAlarmSettings", "android.content.Context", "java.util.List", new XC_MethodHook() {
```

or just use `hookAllConstructors`

By the way: your call to findAndHookConstructor seems to include the name of the constructor. This is not an expected parameter! Constructor names are always the class name, and xposed doesn't expect you to pass it.

Comment: Removing the constructor name and adding the super instance worked perfectly. Thank you very much!